# Blender Object jitters/shaking while animated along path

Tags: animation

I'm using Blender 2.9 and having the classic object jittering/shaking issue when it follows a path (Bezier Circle). It may be a floating point issue.

I saw a solution, which suggests to parent the object to  world Origin Object. But I'm not sure what it means...

Any suggestions? It'd be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe your curve doesn't have enough resolution?

Comment: I think that I know the answer, but what would be your way of increasing resolution?

Comment: select the curve and in the Properties panel > Object Data > Shape > Resolution. What solution have you found?

Comment: My shape resolution in U direction  under Shape is set to 64. It was much lower. I tried with 64, I'm not sure if this fixed the issue...

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your  time. I did upload the .blend file. It's a simple Follow Path constraint of a cube to a circle. The cube image jitters/shakes on the path. Not sure why... Appreciate your  help. Here is  the  link  I  was given by the  system: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=v9D80Dam" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/v9D80Dam/)

Comment: I've tested and I rendered a video, but I can't see any problem, it seems to work fine to me

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what the problem  then.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm having the same issue when having an object follow a path...